# Appending a hyperlink

Tags: python

I am trying to append a hyperlink "http://data/CR/" to  like below,for some reason its not getting appended..anyidea what is wrong here?

```
INFO = """
<tr>
<td><a href= \"http://data/CR/\" + "{CR}">{CR}</a></td>
<td>{FA}</td>
<td>{CL}</td>
<td>{Title}</td>
</tr>
"""
for item in CRlist[1:]:
    CRstring += INFO.format(
        CR=item[0],
        FA=item[1],
        CL=item[2],
        Title=item[3],
        )
```

Comment: Is "<td><a href= \"http://data/CR/\" + "{CR}">{CR}</a></td>" the right syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on your last attempt at a question when it got deleted. Assuming CRlist from your previous question item[0] is always empty so your URL will never get formed.

As for how you formatted your url you don't need to escape your double quotes since you are in a multi-line string. You also don't need the + or extra quoting around it. Just type it exactly like you want to see it.

```
CRlist = [['CR', 'FA', 'CL', 'TITLE'],
          ['', '409452', 'WLAN', '656885\tAge out RSSI values from buffer in Beacon miss scenario'],
          ['', '415560', 'WLAN', '656886\tTo Record SMD Event Logging'],
          ['', '413064', 'wlan', '654661\tTo Record HAL and SLM FW Event Logging'],
          ['', '379104', 'BT', '656928\tCR379104: BT doesn\xe2\x80\x99t work that Riva neither sends HCI Evt for HID ACL data nor response to HCI_INQUIRY after entering into pseudo sniff subrating mode.']]
CRstring = ''
INFO = """
<tr>
<td><a href="http://data/CR/{CR}">{CR}</a></td>
<td>{FA}</td>
<td>{CL}</td>
<td>{Title}</td>
</tr>
"""
for item in CRlist[1:]:
    print item
    CRstring += INFO.format(
        CR=item[0],
        FA=item[1],
        CL=item[2],
        Title=item[3],
        )
print CRstring
```